# $ can not be used in separate Spark method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Column, SparkSession}

object addColumn {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("hi")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("sample spark job").config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = Seq((1,"a"),(2,"aa"),(3,"bc")).toDF("num","string")
    val newDf = df.withColumn("newColumn", $"string".contains("a"))
    newDf.show()
  }

  def addColumn(df:DataFrame, fixedString: String, columnName: String): DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn(columnName, $"string".contains(fixedString))
  }
}
```

I have code like this in Scala Spark and the main purpose of this code is to add a new column to a Spark DataFrame. The $ method cannot be recognized in addColumn method, anyone has any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: The simplest solution is to implicitly pass the **spark** variable and then `import spark.implicits._` in that method.

Comment: Then I have to also add `SparkSession` to this method as well.

Comment: `def addColumn(df:DataFrame,
                fixedString: String,
                columnName: String,
                spark:SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._
    df.withColumn(columnName, $"string".contains(fixedString))
  }`

Comment: Then when other people call it, it will become complicated to use cuz each time they need to add SparkSession.

Comment: That is why I said **implicitly** `def addColum(df:DataFrame, fixedString: String, columnName: String)(implicit spark:SparkSession): DataFrame = { ... }` and you have to make the original instance implicit too `implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder ...`. Also, you may make that method an **extension** method, to simplify even more its use. - Another alternative would be to do not use the `$` String interpolator at all, and just call `col` on the df directly.

Comment: This helps! Let me accept it!

Comment: alternatively, just use `col` function instead of `$` to create a column